# Interpreting the rotation matrix with respect to a defined World coordinates

Tags: python, opencv, camera-calibration, rotational-matrices, photogrammetry

In the image bellow, we see a defined world plane coordinate (X,Y,0) where Z=0. The camera as we can see is heading towards the defined world plane.

World reference point is located on the top left of the Grid (0,0,0). The distance between every two yellow point **is 40 cm**

[image: World_coordinate]

I've calibrated my camera using the checkerboard and then used the built-in function **cv2.solvePnP** in order to estimate the rotation and translation vector of the camera with respect to my defined world coordinates. The results are as follows:

```
   tvec_cam= [[-5.47884374]
               [-3.08581371]
               [24.15112048]]
   rvec_cam= [[-0.02823308]
              [ 0.08623225]
              [ 0.01563199]]
```

According to the results, the (tx,ty,tz) seems to be right as the camera is located in the negative quarter of X,Y world-coordinates

However, i'm getting confused by interpreting the rotation vector.!

**Does the resulted rotation vector say that the camera coordinates are almost aligned with the world coordinate axis (means almost no rotation!)?,**

If yes how could this be true?, since **according to OPENCV's camera coordinates**, the Z-axis of the camera is pointing towards the scene (which means towards the world plane), the X-axis points towards the image write (which means opposite of X-world axis) and the Y-axis of the camera points towards the image bottom (which also means opposite of the Y-world axis)

**Moreover, what is the unit of the tvec?**

**Note:** I've illustrated the orientation of the defined world-coordinate axis according the the result of the translation vector (both tx and ty are negative)

the code i used for computing the rotation and translation vectors is shown below:

```
import cv2 as cv 
import numpy as np


WPoints = np.zeros((9*3,3), np.float64)
WPoints[:,:2] = np.mgrid[0:9,0:3].T.reshape(-1,2)*0.4




imPoints=np.array([[20,143],[90,143],[161,143],[231,144],[303,144],
              [374,144],[446,145],[516,146],[587,147],[18,214],[88,214]
               ,[159,215],[230,215],[302,216],[374,216],[446,216]
               ,[517,217],[588,217],[16,285],[87,285],[158,286],[229,287], 
                [301,288]
               ,[374,289],[446,289],[518,289],[589,289]],dtype=np.float64)
      
    
#load the rotation matrix [[4.38073915e+03 0.00000000e+00 1.00593352e+03]
                       #  [0.00000000e+00 4.37829226e+03 6.97020491e+02]
                     #    [0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00]]
with np.load('parameters_cam1.npz') as X:
mtx, dist, _, _ = [X[i] for i in ('mtx','dist','rvecs','tvecs')]


ret,rvecs, tvecs = cv.solvePnP(WPoints, imPoints, mtx, dist)


np.savez("extrincic_camera1.npz",rvecs=rvecs,tvecs=tvecs)

print(tvecs)
print(rvecs)
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

The code for estimating the intrinsic is show below

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import glob
import argparse
import pathlib
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-p", "--path", required=True, help="path to images folder")
ap.add_argument("-e", "--file_extension", required=False, default=".jpg", 
help="extension of images")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
path = args["path"] + "*" + args["file_extension"]
# termination criteria
criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 0.001)

# prepare object points, like (0,0,0), (0.03,0,0), (0.06,0,0) ...., 
#(0.18,0.12,0)
objp = np.zeros((5*7,3), np.float32)
objp[:,:2] = np.mgrid[0:7,0:5].T.reshape(-1,2)*0.03
#print(objp)


# Arrays to store object points and image points from all the images.
objpoints = [] # 3d point in real world space
imgpoints = [] # 2d points in image plane.

#images = glob.glob('left/*.jpg') #read a series of images

images = glob.glob(path)

path = 'foundContours'
#pathlib.Path(path).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True) 

found = 0
for fname in images: 
    
  img = cv2.imread(fname) # Capture frame-by-frame
  #print(images[im_i])
  gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
  # Find the chess board corners
  ret, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(gray, (7,5), None)
  #  print(corners)
  # If found, add object points, image points (after refining them)
  if ret == True:
    print('true')
    objpoints.append(objp)   # Certainly, every loop objp is the same, in 3D.
    #print('obj_point',objpoints)
    corners2 = cv2.cornerSubPix(gray,corners,(11,11),(-1,-1),criteria)
    # print(corners2)
    imgpoints.append(corners2)
    print(imgpoints)
    print('first_point',imgpoints[0])
    #print(imgpoints.shape())
    # Draw and display the corners
    img = cv2.drawChessboardCorners(img, (7,5), corners2, ret)
    found += 1
    cv2.imshow('img', img)
    cv2.waitKey(1000)
    # if you want to save images with detected corners 
    # uncomment following 2 lines and lines 5, 18 and 19
    image_name = path + '/calibresult' + str(found) + '.jpg'
    cv2.imwrite(image_name, img)

print("Number of images used for calibration: ", found)

# When everything done, release the capture
# cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
#calibration
ret, mtx, dist, rvecs, tvecs = cv2.calibrateCamera(objpoints, imgpoints, 
gray.shape[::-1],None,None)


#save parameters needed in undistortion
np.savez("parameters_cam1.npz",mtx=mtx,dist=dist,rvecs=rvecs,tvecs=tvecs)
np.savez("points_cam1.npz",objpoints=objpoints,imgpoints=imgpoints)

print ("Camera Matrix = |fx  0 cx|")
print ("                | 0 fy cy|")
print ("                | 0  0  1|")
print (mtx)
print('distortion coefficients=\n', dist)
print('rotation vector for each image=', *rvecs, sep = "\n")
print('translation vector for each image=', *tvecs, sep= "\n")
```

Hope you could help me understanding this

Thanks in Advance

Comment: @morynicz would appreciate your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, **tvec** is a in Axis-angle representation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axis%E2%80%93angle_representation).

You can obtain the rotation matrix using cv2.Rodrigues(). For your data, I get almost the identity:

```
[[ 0.99616253 -0.01682635  0.08588995]
 [ 0.01439347  0.99947963  0.02886672]
 [-0.08633098 -0.02751969  0.99588635]]
```

Now, according to the directions of **x** and **y** in your picture, the z-axis points **downwards** (apply carefully the right-hand rule). This explains why the z-axis of the camera is almost aligned with the z-axis of your world reference frame.

---

**Edit**: Digging a little bit further, from the code you posted:

```
WPoints = np.zeros((9*3,3), np.float64)
WPoints[:,:2] = np.mgrid[0:9,0:3].T.reshape(-1,2)*0.4
```

The values for X and Y are all positive and increment to the right and to the bottom respectively, so you are indeed using the usual convention. **You are actually using X and Y incrementing to the right and down respectively and what's wrong is only the arrows you drew in the picture**.

---

**Edit** Concerning the interpretation of the translation vector: in the OpenCV convention, the points in the local camera reference frame are obtained from the points in the world reference frame like this:

```
|x_cam|          |x_world|
|y_cam| = Rmat * |y_world| + tvec
|z_cam|          |z_world|
```

With this convention, **tvec** is the position of the world origin  in the camera reference frame. What's more easily interpretable is the position of the camera origin in the world reference frame, which can be obtained as:

```
cam_center = -(tvec * R_inv)
```

Where R_inv is the inverse of the rotation matrix. Here the rotation matrix is almost the identity, so a quick approximation would be **-tvec**, which is (5.4, 3.1, -24.1).

Comment: @Milo.Thanks a lot for the answer, I've uploaded the code from which i computed the tvec and rvec. Yes i set Z values to z=0 for all world points on the Grid since all points lay on a plane. For your wondering about the axis-alignment, i'm wondering two since SolvePnP considers the the camera axis direction same as image coordinates. ( x axe pointing in the right side from the camera, y axe is pointing down, and z is pointing in the direction camera is faced). Thus, my defined world axes direction is the opposite accordingly

Comment: The convention i used for image coordinates is as you said top-left corner with increasing to the right and y increasing to the bottom

Comment: Updated the answer. If you think this answers your question, you could mark it as solved.

Comment: .I've drown the arrows like in the picture according to the values of the rotation vector (tx and ty are negative).

Comment: Despite the fact that, as you said X and Y world points increment in the same direction as image points, the value of the translation vector is negative. Do you know why ?

Comment: Updated the answer (don't forget to mark it as accepted :-) ) The values of the computed position for the camera seem too big. This could be caused by a wrong estimation of the focal distance during intrinsic calibration; what values do you use for the 3D coordinates of the calibration grid? 0, 1, 2, 3... ?

Comment: for the calibration grid i used checkerboard and implemented the Zang's method (17 images with different orientation and translation) and the distance between the corners is (3cm)

Comment: @Milo.Regarding the value of translation vector, That is exactly my wonder, they are two big. However, when  use the tvec along with rvec for estimating the homography and then use it to locate the 3D point of my detected 2D point, it gives a true and correct value

Comment: according your last update the tvec is (5.4, 3.1, -24.1). Does the Z axes of the camera coordinate still aligned with the defined Z axes of the world coordinates?

Comment: 1. The z-axes are still aligned, but as Z points down through the floor, the camera is in the negative side of the z-axis. 2. at some point during the intrinsic calibration you passed the 3D coordinates of the points of the grid. In most tutorials in the Internet, you use integer coordinates, like (0, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (1, 0, 0) with x and y equal to 0, 1, 2... and z=0. What values do you used?

Comment: you're write about the Z coordinate is still aligned according to write hand rule. However, have you got any idea why tvec is too big. The camera matrix is actually correct. However, do you think that i should re-calibrate the camera with more images?

Comment: I don't think so. What I think is that you don't scaled properly the grid coordinates to obtain the right focal distance. Could you post the code you used for intrinsic calibration?

Comment: I've updated the question . I really appreciate your help. @Milo

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220874/discussion-between-milo-and-k-jbaili).